# shell functions and argument passing issue

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, arguments

I'm in need to pass arguments to a shell script, which after validation, need to be passed on to a function in the script either as same or after modification.

```
#!/bin/sh
func1(){
echo "called func1 with $1" ;
exit 0 ;
}

func2(){
echo "called func2 with $1" ;
exit 0 ;
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage:" ;
    echo "script.sh arg1 arg2" ;
    exit -1 ;
fi

if [ "$1" -eq "txt1" ]
then
    func1 $2 ;
    exit 0 ;
fi

if ["$1" -eq "txt2" ]
then
    func2 $2 ;
    exit 0;
fi
```

The response I get is

```
sh script.sh txt1
sh: txt1: bad number
sh: txt1: bad number
```

Comment: Instead of lots of cascading `if`s, you might want to use a `case` statement.

Comment: BTW, it's not just the test that needs quotes to ensure that content is passed without modification; you also want `func1 "$2"` and `func2 "$2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator for string comparison. You want to use `=`, not `-eq` (which is comparing integers).

Note that `[` is just an internal command of the shell, so you need to separate that with whitespace from its arguments. (At the third test in your script.)

Comment: Might also mention the need for whitespace (missing in the second invocation).

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I'm new to both STCK OVFL and linux shell.
Also, I thought the response would help some of the newbies like me who search for the response rather than a question list?